# Setting mailbox folder permissions through Powershell fails

Tags: powershell, permissions, office365, exchange-server

I want to share other peoples Office 365 calendars with me, with different access rights for testing. I have Exchange admin rights so that I can poke around in the Office365 Exchange config.

With https://theitbros.com/add-calendar-permissions-in-office-365-via-powershell/ as inspiration and some help from https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d59a04ec-3d9d-40c1-8937-fedfba79b888/assigned-reviewer-access-rights-through-powershell-but-can-create-calendar-appointments?forum=Exch2016PS I have done the following

- Start Powershell as admin
- Log into Office365:
  `$LiveCred = Get-Credential`
- Create a new session:
  `$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $LiveCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection`
- Import the Office365 session:
  `Import-PSSession $Session`
- Query the mailbox folder statistics with `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics`, but filter on 'identity':
  `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics b@tdomain.onmicrosoft.com | fl identity`
  This shows names for these 'Identities' and tells me that the calendar in Dutch is called `Agenda`.
- Update the permissions for those folders:
  `Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity t@tdomain.onmicrosoft.com:\Agenda -user jandoggen@tdomain.onmicrosoft.com -AccessRights PublishingEditor`
  `Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity i@tdomain.onmicrosoft.com:\Agenda -user jandoggen@tdomain.onmicrosoft.com -AccessRights Editor`
  `Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity b@tdomain.onmicrosoft.com:\Agenda -user jandoggen@tdomain.onmicrosoft.com -AccessRights Reviewer`

If I now verify the permissions with

```
Get-MailboxFolderPermission t@tdomain.onmicrosoft.com:\Agenda
Get-MailboxFolderPermission i@tdomain.onmicrosoft.com:\Agenda
Get-MailboxFolderPermission b@tdomain.onmicrosoft.com:\Agenda
```

... I see access rights `{PublishingEditor}`, `{Editor}` and `{Reviewer}`:

[image]

**However**, in OWA (Outlook Web Access) I can still create appointments in b's calendar, where it says {Reviewer}.
What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

**First:** it looks like giving PublishingEditor gives you the rights needed to Create/Remove items.  I suggest digging into AccessRights.. More here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/105ccad6-4d36-4c6b-a2e1-8cc890fde9fb/addmailboxpermission-accessrights-definition?forum=exchangesvrgeneral

Specifically, this:

[image]

**Second:** Are you Dutch by any chance? I have never seen the ':\agenda' switch used before.  From what I have found, only when using the Dutch language 'pack' should you use ':\agenda'.

Please try those same commands, but use ':\calendar' instead of ':\agenda'.  I am not sure if this will have any affect, but it is a good start.

Found here: http://www.vdberge.com/kennisbank/a-quick-way-to-set-calendar-permissions-using-powershell/

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity t@tdomain.onmicrosoft.com:\Calendar -user jandoggen@tdomain.onmicrosoft.com -AccessRights PublishingEditor, Editor, Reviewer
```

**Third:** it looks like the permissions you are assigning do not make sense. Please review access rights and the permissions that encompasses them.

Comment: Yes, the Dutch is specific. That's why I do the Get-MailboxFolderStatistic: to determine what the folder name is. It is *not* Calendar (*that* failed)

Comment: Gotcha.  I agree this has nothing to do with the overall issue. I believe the overall issue has to do with the AccessRights.

Giving someone PublishingEditor would allow someone to edit an agenda - this is expected behavior.  The issue here is the rights you are assigning.

Comment: *I can still create appointments in b's calendar, where it says {Reviewer}.*

Comment: If you remove "Reviewer" permissions, are you still able to create appointments in B's calendar?